# Freezegun does not work on django orm create_at field

Tags: python, python-2.7, django-orm, freezegun

I am trying to use freezegun for unittest:

```
    class Customer(models.Model):
        created_at = models.DateTimeField(default=datetime.now, null=True)


    from freezegun import freeze_time

    with freeze_time(datetime(2020, 9, 9, 9), tz_offset=9):
            customer = Customer.objects.create()
            print 'created at', customer.created_at

    # prints: created at 2020-11-27 19:54:11.994688
```

So it seems like the freezetime isn't working for django orm for some reason.
I am unable to do `Customer.objects.create(created_at=...)` in the function I am trying to test.

How can I correctly set the *created_at* time using freezegun?

Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you pass the *function* directly, hence when the `freezegun` overrides the `datetime.now` attribute, that has no impact on the references to the *old* function.

An alternative might be to make a custom function where you each time retrieve the attribute:

```
def current_time():
    return datetime.now()

class Customer(models.Model):
        created_at = models.DateTimeField(default=current_time, null=True)
```

But Django actually already has a way to use the time of creation: you can specify [**`auto_now_add=True`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.DateTimeField.auto_now_add):

```
class Customer(models.Model):
        created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, null=True)
```

This will also set the field to [**`editable=False`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#editable) such that, by default, it does not show up in a `ModelForm`.

Comment: Oh wow, I've spent so long on this issue.. Thank you so much! (bought you a coffee just now ;D) Thank you Willem!